# How to install your source as a package on heroku

Tags: heroku, pip, containers

Im looking to install a custom package on heroku. I have the following folder structure.

```
├─ src
│  ├─ packagename
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  └─ ...
│  └─ setup.py
├─ tests
│  └─ ...
└─ Procfile
```

Locally I run the following to make the package structure importable.

```
$ cd src
$ pip install -e .
```

How do I add that step to build process in heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to add it to the `requirements.txt` file with the -e flag. Found it out from looking at the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#local-file-backed-distributions) on how to handle local file-backed distributions.